# Mongoose filter In populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image]

I am trying to populate with subdocument filter like this. Population working But filter not working. Can anyone help?

My Course model

[image]

My Section Model

[image]

My Lesson Model

[image]